# Webix add tooltip to specific elements in treetable

Tags: webix, webix-treetable

This example, [Click Here](https://docs.webix.com/samples/15_datatable/32_grouping/03_aggregation.html) has column votes with set of number value. And I want add tooltips for elements which has more than 400 votes. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need add **tooltip** property in treetable configuration:

```
tooltip: (obj, common) => {
  return (obj.votes > 400 && common.column.id === "votes") ? 
  "Your text here" : ""
}
```

Demo snippet is here: https://webix.com/snippet/2ffa6713

In this example tooltip shown only on votes column.